# Compactness theorem, directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, logic, compactness

We study a language L and the axioms of directed graphs. A directed graph is connected if there's for every 2 points a finite path.
Prove that ther's no theory T such that it contains the axioms of a directed graph, and such that for every directed graph M concerns: M is a model of T <=> M is connected.

I started with presuming that there exists such a theory. So I built up T' = T U {axioms for no connected graph}. This theory is inconsistent, so there's an finite subtheory that is also inconsistent..
But now I don't know how to say it correct.

Thanks in advance
Silke

Comment: What is the signature of your language? Symbols for "object", "arrow", "domain", "codomain"?

Answer (score 3):

For $n\in\omega$ let $[n]=\{0,\ldots,n\}$, and let $C_n$ be the directed graph with vertex set $[n]$ and edge set $\{\langle k,\ell\rangle\in[n]\times[n]:|k-\ell|=1\}$; $C_n$ is a two-way chain of length $n$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\omega$, and let $$G=\left(\prod_{n\in\omega}C_n\right)/\mathscr{U}\;,$$ the ultraproduct of the graphs $G_n$. Can you find two vertices of $G$ which are not connected by any finite path? I’ve left an answer, spoiler-protected, below; mouse-over to see it.

> Let $u:\omega\to\omega:n \mapsto 0$ and $v:\omega\to\omega:n\mapsto n$; there is no finite path from $[u]_\mathscr{U}$ to $[v]_\mathscr{U}$.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the compactness theorem. Given $T$, can you add symbols $a,b$ and axioms stating "$a,b$ are vertices at a distance > $n$" for all $n$?

Comment: So I have to add 2 extra symbols to the language L? And then I define phi_n = {V(a) and V(b) and distance(a,b) =n}.

Comment: Then work with the theory T' = T Union {not phi_n | n natural number}

Comment: There may be a technical issue with adding "not phi_n", since you've defined phi_n to include the statements that $a$ and $b$ are vertices. So "not phi_n" could be satisfied trivially by a model where $a$ and $b$ are not vertices. I think it would be cleaner to define phi_n = {V(a) and V(b) and distance(a,b) **!=** n} and then T' = T Union {phi_n | n natural number}. Or, as I originally proposed, distance(a,b) > n; either way should work.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got it!